pagination rules copy activity Odata.nextlink
I am not sure what am I doing wrong.
I am using a copy activity getting data from REST API OData  and has oData.nextLink for next page.
When I use

the copy activity runs only from base Url but does not go into the next page link and so on.
This is Json I have from api postman ( which is source of copy activity)
{
"@odata.context": "https://baseurl/api/v1/dataexport/providers/5j4/$metadata#FactData/$delta",
"value": [
{
"@odata.context": "#FactData/$entity",
"@odata.id": "FactData(,CHANNEL='%23',PRODUCT='3',COMPANY='10')",
"RATE_PERCENT": null,
"AMT": 597086,
"UNITS": null
}
],
"@odata.nextLink": "https:/baseurl/contextID=4d240943-5d06-477e-94ba-9a340152cdef",
}

Did you got any error?

no error but count is only giving the base url count and not the whole data. so I know it didnt work.

As per your JSON and key value name which is @odata.nextLink, you need to give the below value in the pagination. After selecting AbsoluteUrl, set the value as None and then give this value.
$['@odata.nextLink']


Here, as your key name contains a ., you are using . notation in the pagination rules but this will search for the key nextLink inside the @odata object which does not exist instead of the key @odata.nextLink. So, using the [] notation for this type of key names will give the expected results.

You are God Sent. Thanks so much. That worked.
